# Testing if NetworkStream is closed

Tags: .net, networking, stream

I have a class, that wrapps a Stream instance, so I can use it for wrapping FileStreams and NetworkStreams. Now, I want to test if the stream is still delivering any data, in other words, I want to test the NetworkStream if it is still connected or the FileStream if it reached its end.

Is there any function whose return value I can use to determine if the next Stream.Read() will cause an exception?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what exception you are seeing? I'd honestly like to know.

Answer (score 3):

`Stream.Read` shouldn't throw an exception at the end; it returns something non-positive. I just Read(...) until I get back this - i.e.

```
int read;
while((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0) {
    // process "read"-many bytes
}
```

Note that `NetworkStream` has a [`DataAvailable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.dataavailable.aspx) - but this refers to the **buffer**, not the stream itself (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166530/does-networkstream-dataavailable-see-buffered-data)). I mention this only so you **don't** try to use it to see if the stream is closed, since that isn't what it means.

If you wrap your `Stream` in a `StreamReader`, then you can use [`Peek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.peek.aspx) or [`EndOfStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.endofstream.aspx) to test for closure:

```
bool isEnd = reader.EndOfStream;
```

or:

```
int b = reader.Peek();
if(b < 0) {... was end ...}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this did not solve my problem. I'm fine with exception handling right now. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
stream.CanRead
```

Answer (score 0):

The NetworkStream will return EOF (Read will return 0 bytes) when the other side closes the socket.